# Python 3: notImplementedError "undefined name" warning

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class, notimplementedexception

I have got the warning "undefined name notImplemented error" in spyder code analysis in the abstract class presented below:

```
class Shape:        # define parent class
   parametersList = []
   def __init__(self,parametersList,color):
       self.parametersList=parametersList
       self.color=color
   def print_color(self):
       # Prints object color
       raise notImplementedError
   def eval_area(self):   
       # Evals area
       raise notImplementedError
```

What is happening?

Comment: There is a syntax error. It is `NotImplementedError` instead of `notImplementedError`. By the way what IDE do you use? Any IDE should have told you that it is a unknown keyword.

Comment: Spyder in Anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, try capitalizing "NotImplementedError". If thats not the case then I believe [this thread](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/PYTHON/NotImplemented+is+not+an+Exception) from Semmle might give you a lead on the situation otherwise.